# How to look for a pattern that might be missing some characters, but following a certain order?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a validation for `"KQkq" <or> "-"`, in the first case, any of the letters can be missing (expect all of them, in which case it should be `"-"`). The **order** of the characters is also important.

So quick examples of legal examples are:

- `-`
- `Kkq`
- `q`

This is for a Chess [FEN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) validation, I have validated the first two parts using:.

```js
var fen_parts = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
fen_parts = fen_parts.split(" ");

if(!fen_parts[0].replace(/[1-8/pnbrqk]/gi,"").length
&& !fen_parts[1].replace(/[wb]/,"").length
&& !fen_parts[2].replace(/[kq-]/gi,"").length /*not working, allows KKKKKQkq to be valid*/
){
    //...
}
```

But simply using `/[kq-]/gi` to validate the third part allows too many things to be introduced, here are some quick examples of illegal examples:

- `KKKKQkq` (there is more than one K)
- `QK` (order is incorrect)

Comment: ([K]?[Q]?[k]?[q]?|-) does that do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
-|K?Q?k?q?
```

though you will need to do a second test to ensure that the input is not empty. Alternatively, using only regex:

```
KQ?k?q?|Qk?q?|kq?|q|-
```

Comment: Huh...why don't you use `match` instead of `replace`, and the anchors `^` and `$` to ensure the full string is matched?

Comment: sorry my first comment was wrong, `K?Q?k?q?|-` works! (except with `"-"` but I am sure I can fix that part)

Comment: uh..if that works for you, then you didn't properly describe your needs...that pattern will allow for instance "QK" didn't you say they needed to be in order?

Comment: @CrayonViolent: No, it doesn't allow `QK`...what gives you that idea?

Comment: any ideas why `"-".replace(/([K]?[Q]?[k]?[q]?|-)/,"")` doesn't remove `-`?

Comment: @CrayonViolent: That's because it matched "Q". You need global anchors to use `match`.

Comment: @Gaph: My fault! `-` needs to be in the first branch since the second branch can match an empty string.

Comment: @nneonneo oh you mean like this? `"QK".match(/^-|K?Q?k?q?$/)` That doesn't return null either...

Comment: Uh, because you put the anchors in different branches.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me...

`^(-|(K)?((?!\2)Q)?((?!\2\3)k)?((?!\2\3\4)q)?)$`

Answer (score 0):

A `.match()` returns `null` if the expression did not match. In that case you can use the `logical OR` to default to an array with an empty-string (a structure similar to the one returned by `.match()` on a successful match), which will allow you to check the length of the matched expression. The length will be `0` if the expression did not match, or `K?Q?k?q?` matched the empty string. If the pattern matches, the length will be `> 0`. in code:

```
("KQkq".match(/^(?:K?Q?k?q?|-)$/) || [""])[0].length
```

Because `|` is "stronger" than you'd expect, it is necessary to wrap your actual expression in a non-capturing group `(?:)`.

---

Having answered the question, let's have a look at the rest of your code:

```
if (!fen_parts[0].replace(/[1-8/pnbrqk]/gi,"").length)
```

is, from the javascript's perspective equivalent to

```
if (!fen_parts[0].match(/[^1-8/pnbrqk]/gi))
```

which translates to "false if any character but `1-8/pnbrqk`". This notation is not only simpler to read, it also executes faster as there is no unnecessary string mutation (replace) and computation (length) going on.